# Determining Onto/One-to-one of this function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have this problem and I think I have it down for onto, but my reasoning with the one-to-one I am not confident about.

Let $g : \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}→\mathbb{Z}$ and $g(a,b) = a^2 - b$

Is this function one-to-one? Is this function onto?

1. Onto:

Would say **yes it is onto** because you can set $a=0, b=-y$ when $a^2 - b = y$ and get $y=y$

2. One-to-one:

Would say **yes it is one-to-one** because if you set $g(a,b) \neq g(b, a)$ when you plug in values for a and b where $a \neq b $

However, I considered the case where $a=1,b=3$ being mapped to the same range value (-2) as happens when $a=-1,b=3$ Can I take the two into consideration this way?  This would make it **not one-to-one**

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, but your conclusion is flawed.  The fact that $g(1,0)=g(-1,0)$ proves the function is not $1:1$.

Comment: @lulu thank you for clarifying for me

Comment: @lulu how do I accept your answer as correct for this?

Comment: one-to-one can be the quickest remembered as: It is not allowed that two mapping arrows point to the same image point. So $g(a,b)\neq g(c,d)$ is irrelevant in this context. $(a,b)\neq (c,d)$ and $g(a,b)=g(c,d)$ would be the case to be considered - as you did with your example $(a,b)=(-1,0),(c,d)=(1,0).$

Comment: Even if you restrict the domain to non-negative integers, it is not $1:1$   For example, $g(1,1)=g(2,4)$.

Comment: @MariusS.L. that is very helpful and I placed it on my notes sheet

Comment: No need to accept my answer...you can post a solution yourself.  People can then review it for you.

Answer (score 1):

As @lulu and @MariusS.L. point out -- it is not one-to-one because it is arbitrarily easy to show that $(a,b)=(−1,0),(c,d)=(1,0)$  You don't restrict yourself to just the two variables $a,b$.  You consider any mappings which place multiple inputs to one output.  And when this happens, the function is not one-to-one by definition.